# Is this an efficient way to display an image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works, but is it an efficient way to go about displaying an image once it has been loaded?

```
LightBoxNamespace.SetupLightBox = function(path, lightBox) {

    // Create a new image.
    var image = new Image();

    // The onload function must come before we set the image's src, see link for explanation.
    // http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called.

    // Anonymous function set to onload event, to make sure we only proceed if the image has been loaded.
    image.onload = function () {

      if ($('#image').length) {
        $('#image').attr('src', path); // If the element already exists, change the src to our loaded image. 
      }
      else {
        $('<img id="image" alt="">').attr('src', path).insertAfter('#close'); // If the element does not exist, insert the full image html into the lightbox.
      }

      LightBoxNamespace.CentreBoxInViewport(lightBox);
      LightBoxNamespace.ShowOverlay(lightBox);
    };

    // Set the src, and show the image.
    image.src = path;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var img = $('<img>');
  img.load(function(){alert("image loaded!")});
  img.attr('src', "url");
  if (!! img) img.appendTo('#close');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W57QR/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have said in the original question, but I want to avoid having a html img attribute with no src as I tried this, and its causing errors in my rails application.

Comment: then attach it while creating the img element, http://jsfiddle.net/W57QR/5/, like this?

Answer (score 0):

"The jQuery way":

```
var $img = $('<img/>').prop({ src: path });

$img.load(function() { 
    console.log('image loaded correctly'); 
    $(this).insertAfter('#close'); 
}).error(function() { 
    console.log('error loading image'); 
});
```

Comment: Back in the days, I learned to assign the `load` event before giving the `img` a `src`. I don't know if it really matters, but I could *imagine* some crazy ass scenario where the `img` is ready before you assign the event, so maybe he already did that in a better way?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus you appear correct, if the image loads before you set load it wont work, jsfiddleoritdidnthappen: http://jsfiddle.net/W57QR/1/